# Spring security OAuth - check validity of access token?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am following this sample code from [Spring Security OAuth](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/oauth2-vanilla).

After I got the access token when I try to check the token

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/check_token -d "token=e3f44c4f-f8f2-45c4-9f9e-c7dd1f583a1f"
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

I tried passing client id and secret.

```
curl -X POST acme:acmesecret@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/check_token -d "token=e3f44c4f-f8f2-45c4-9f9e-c7dd1f583a1f"
```

I get 403 status.

```
{"timestamp":1437683976536,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access is denied","path":"/uaa/oauth/check_token”}
```

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong. 
Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please specify what is the definition of  `../uaa/oauth/check_token`? I am asking because there is no such standard  endpoint..

Comment: it is `/oauth/check_token` which validates the access token. `/uaa/` is just contextPath.

Comment: What exactly it does? If you have a token already why you have to validate it? If `check_token` endpoint already secured with oauth then you have to provide an Authentication header within your request and not the parameter... This header should be: `Authentication: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN`

Comment: `check_token` is not secured with oauth. please have a look at link in the post above to get more information on its use

Answer (score 16):

Try to play with `/check_token` authorization rights via:

```
public class OAuthSecurityConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override 
   public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception { 
       oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");  I will suggest using oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()"); which is more secure than opening it up. Any client wanting to check token will have to supply their client credentials

Comment: @SeunMatt what with Single Page Applications and Implict or Authorization Code flow? I mean, SPA client can't authenticate itself because it is insecure to store client credentials in SPA app